# Is copyediting good for an academic career?

Tags: publications, journals, career-path, editors

I have recently been involved in managing a special issue in a scientific journal. The chief-editor was somehow appreciative of my work and now wants me to join the journal's board as a [copyeditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_editing). I am puzzled by this request since I have no example of an academic being involved in such a task. Usually, being an editor (see [Why become a journal editor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/why-become-a-journal-editor)) involves more content evaluation.

Would my academic career take advantage of such a duty?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only benefit you'll get as a copyeditor is clear: **money** (assuming he offered to pay you).

The downsides are numerous: it takes a lot of time, it will not be considered a plus to your CV (it's a technical job, not a scientific one)… none of the benefits from being a journal editor apply to a copyeditor.

Also, I don't know exactly what you did when you say *“I have recently been involved in managing a special issue”*, but if you were guest editor, **offering you a copyeditor job is clearly not showing appreciation for your job** as a scientist.

Comment: While I generally agree with your answer, isn't this a bit too harsh "*...it will not be considered a plus to your CV (it's a technical job, not a scientific one)*"? Writing skills are an important part of being a scientist, and being a (good) copy-editor shows that you have strong writing skills and can evaluate texts critically (logical consistency etc).

Comment: "Technical or scientific job" is a nice way of summarizing the question. The specificity of this journal is that it is both in French and English (usually, an English article with an additional French summary). A copy editor would therefore be involved in the consistency of wording (technical) and concepts/notions (scientific).

Comment: @fileunderwater I stand by my wording: a great way to show good writing skills is by writing good papers, good research projects and a good application/letters. Being copyeditor is negligible in applications…

Comment: @F'x Yes, but due to funding, job opportunities and interests people choose different paths, and I do not think that copyediting work for a scientific journal should be seen as completely irrelevant (if coupled to actual scientific work). But I agree that in a direct comparison of CVs more science > copyediting experience.