# Does IEEE have any payment for its journal editors?

Tags: journals, editors, ieee

In response to the post "[Why become a journal editor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/why-become-a-journal-editor)", some mentioned that certain editorial members, such as the Editor-in-Chief or other editors, receive monetary compensations. I am wondering if the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE) offers any paid editorial positions for its journals. If so, is this information public?

Comment: I can't resist commenting that, whatever the compensation may be, it's surely not enough to motivate any secure faculty to take the position! The motivation would be service. :)